# How to download non-standardized CSB file and pre-process it

Tags: r, csv

I'm interested in historical data of LendingClub, which is the biggest P2P lending company.

It's a non-standardized zipped CSB file but can be remedied easily when open in Excel by deleting the 1st, 39789-39791th, and 42543-42544th lines, how can I do it in R automatically? (If you would like to help but are afraid of this might be a malicious link, please Google this company first)

I tried the following:

```
data <- read.csv(url("https://resources.lendingclub.com/LoanStats3a.csv.zip"))
```

but it throws error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

Comment: You should be clear on exactly what are the steps you would like to perform before importing it? What "few lines" are you deleting? Also, it's probably not a good idea to assume that others are willing to download a (potentially malicious) zip file to help you. Carefully describe the file contents here in the question.

Comment: @MrFlick, Good advice, it's been edited.

Comment: Well it's not malicious, but who ever created that csv file should be fired.  It's absolutely terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `skip` to get past the first "garbage" line, but there are ~4 "garbage" lines at the end you'll need to deal with post-import:

```
dat <- read.csv("LoanStats3a.csv", skip=1, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
str(dat)

## 'data.frame': 42538 obs. of  96 variables:
##  $ id                            : chr  "1077501" "1077430" "1077175" "1076863" ...
##  $ member_id                     : int  1296599 1314167 1313524 1277178 1311748 1311441 1304742 1288686 1306957 1306721 ...
##  $ loan_amnt                     : int  5000 2500 2400 10000 3000 5000 7000 3000 5600 5375 ...
##  $ funded_amnt                   : int  5000 2500 2400 10000 3000 5000 7000 3000 5600 5375 ...
##  $ funded_amnt_inv               : num  4975 2500 2400 10000 3000 ...
##  $ term                          : chr  " 36 months" " 60 months" " 36 months" " 36 months" ...
##  $ int_rate                      : chr  " 10.65%" " 15.27%" " 15.96%" " 13.49%" ...
##  $ installment                   : num  162.9 59.8 84.3 339.3 67.8 ...
##  $ grade                         : chr  "B" "C" "C" "C" ...
##  $ sub_grade                     : chr  "B2" "C4" "C5" "C1" ...
##  $ emp_title                     : chr  "" "Ryder" "" "AIR RESOURCES BOARD" ...
##  $ emp_length                    : chr  "10+ years" "< 1 year" "10+ years" "10+ years" ...
##  ... (a bunch more variables, some are all NA)
```